# CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL and CHANGE_ID environment variables return "No such property: ..."

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Given the following pipeline:

```
stages {
    stage ("Checkout SCM") {
        steps {
            checkout scm

            sh "echo ${CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL}"
            sh "echo ${CHANGE_ID}"
        }
    }
}
```

Why do these variables fail to resolve and provide a value?

Eventually I want to use these environment variables to send an email and merge a pull request:

```
post {
    failure {
        emailext (
        attachLog: true,
        subject: '[Jenkins] $PROJECT_NAME :: Build #$BUILD_NUMBER :: build failure',
        to: '$CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL',
        replyTo: 'iadar@...',
        body: '''<p>You are receiving this email because your pull request was involved in a failed build. Check the attached log file, or the console output at: $BUILD_URL to view the build results.</p>'''
     )
    }
}
```

and

```
sh "curl -X PUT -d '{\'commit_title\': \'Merge pull request\'}'  <git url>/pulls/${CHANGE_ID}/merge?access_token=<token>"
```

Oddly enough, `$PROJECT_NAME`, `$BUILD_NUMBER`, `$BUILD_URL` do work...

---

**Update:** this may be an open bug... https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40486  :-(
Is there any workaround to get these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this, these variables are available only if the checkbox for **Build origin PRs (merged with base branch)** was checked (this is in a multi-branch job).

See more in this other Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39838

Comment: where is this checkbox? I cannot find it in my multi-branch job

Comment: The plug-in has since been updated and this answer is not as valid. Need to update myself so I could updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful about how you refer to environment variables depending on whether it is shell or Groovy code, and how you are quoting.

When you do `sh "echo ${CHANGE_ID}"`, what actually happens is that Groovy will interpolate the string first, by replacing `${CHANGE_ID}` with the Groovy property `CHANGE_ID`, and that's where your error message is from. In Groovy, the environment variables are wrapped in `env`.

If you want to refer to the environment variables directly from your shell script, you either have to interpolate with env, use single quotes, or escape the dollar sign. All of the following should work:

```
sh 'echo $CHANGE_ID'
sh "echo \$CHANGE_ID"
sh "echo ${env.CHANGE_ID}"
```

Comment: What about when using variables not in sh scripts, such as inside emailext plug-in, slack plug-in and alike? I've updated the question with an example for emailext.

Comment: In this case I am getting "Error sending to the following INVALID addresses: $CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL"

Comment: Then you need to use the Groovy style.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes ask the question too soon and then find the answer anyway... Thanks again!

Comment: Actually it seems it's still failing... says Sending email to: ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL}
Error sending to the following INVALID addresses: ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL}

Comment: Okay, it's actually "null" that's why.